# Gaussian Quadrature with Hermite Polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

I want to find a quadrature approximation of $\int f(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$dx. Using the Hermite Polynomials 1, x, $x^2-1$, $x^3-3x$, $x^4 - 6x^2 + 3$. that is exact for polynomials up to order 7.

Now I know by definition it will be exact for polynomials up to order 7 as they are exact up to order 2n - 1, for degree n polynomials. Which holds as our largest degree is 4, and 2*4 - 1 = 7.

I know I want to find some weight function $\alpha_j$ such that $\int f(x)w(x)$ = $\sum^n_{j=1}\alpha_jf(x_j)$.

So I take my set of Hermite polynomials to be my f(x), but how do I find $\alpha_j$. I imagine it has something to do with the Hermite polynomials being orthonormal but I'm not sure of the next step. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a direct formula for $\alpha_j$. If $h_n(x)$ denotes a member of the *orthonormal* system of polynomials in use, the formula is just $\color{blue}{\alpha_j=1/[h_n'(x_j)]^2}$.

To obtain it, we use the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j f(x_j)$ holds if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $2n$. Consider $f_k(x)=h_n(x)/(x-x_k)$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$; it is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, with $f_k(x_j)=0$ for $j\neq k$, and $f_k(x_k)=h_n'(x_k)$. Then $h_n'(x)f_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2n-2$, and we can apply the fact above to it, which yields $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n'(x)f_k(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\alpha_k[h_n'(x_k)]^2.$$

And the integral is evaluated as follows:
\begin{gather}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n'(x)f_k(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx
=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)[f_k(x)e^{-x^2/2}]'\,dx
\\=\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty x h_n(x)f_k(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx}_{\text{use }xf_k(x)=h_n(x)+x_k f_k(x)}-\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)f_k'(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx}_{=0}
\\=\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n^2(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx}_{=1}+x_k\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)f_k(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,dx}_{=0}=1.
\end{gather}

Answer (score 0):

I assume your integration range is the entire real line $(-\infty,\infty)$.  You can integrate all $4$ Hermite polynomials exactly using $\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n(x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\delta_{n,0}$.  By expanding the integral into the sum
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i H_n(x_i)=\sqrt{2\pi}\delta_{n,0}.
$$
Choosing the $x_i$ as the roots of $H_4(x)$ ie, $x\in\{x_i|H_4(x)=0\}$ gives a matrix equation you can solve for $\{\alpha_i\}$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
H_1(x_0) & H_1(x_1) & H_1(x_2) & H_1(x_3) \\
H_2(x_0) & H_2(x_1) & H_2(x_2) & H_2(x_3) \\
H_3(x_0) & H_3(x_1) & H_3(x_2) & H_3(x_3) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0\\ \alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\\ \alpha_3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2\pi} \\ 0 \\0 \\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$